# Laravel 4 login facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-4

A few months ago I created my login with a facebook app. Now that I'm on a new project, I used these routes and the controller (the same as in the previous project) but with a new app for facebook and I had this error

```
Undefined index: username
```

app/routes.php

```
Route::get('login/fb', array('as' => 'facebook.login','uses' => 'SessionController@facebook'));
Route::get('login/fb/callback', array('as' => 'facebook.callback','uses' => 'SessionController@callback'));
Route::get('register',array('as' => 'session.signup','uses' => 'SessionController@create'));
Route::get('logout',array('as' => 'session.logout','uses' => 'SessionController@destroy'))->before('auth');
```

app/controllers/SessionController.php

```
<?php

class SessionController extends BaseController {

public function create()
{
    return View::make('sessions.create');
}

public function store()
{
    $data = array();

    if (Auth::check()) {
        $data = Auth::user();
        return Redirect::intended('/profile')->with('AlertMessage','<p class="alert alert-success">Has iniciado sesión <strong>correctamente</strong></p>');
    }

    return Redirect::intended('/profile')->with('AlertMessage','<p class="alert alert-danger">El usuario y/o la contraseña son <strong>incorrectos</strong></p>');
}

public function show()
{   
        return View::make('sessions.view');
}

public function destroy()
{
    Auth::logout();

    return Redirect::to('/')->with('AlertMessage','<p class="alert alert-info">Has cerrado sesión <strong>correctamente</strong></p>');
}

public function callback()
{
    $code = Input::get('code');
    if (strlen($code) == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');

    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($uid == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error');

    $me = $facebook->api('/me');

    $user = User::whereUid($uid)->first();
    if (empty($user)) {

      $user = new User;
      $user->first_name = $me['first_name'];
      $user->last_name = $me['last_name'];
      $user->email = $me['email'];
      $user->username = $me['username'];
      $user->uid = $uid;

        $user->save();
    }

    $user->access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $user->save();

    Auth::login($user);

    return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Logged in with Facebook');
}

public function facebook()
{
    $facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
    $params = array(
        'redirect_uri' => route('facebook.callback'),
        'scope' => 'email',
    );
    return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
}
}
```

This code works for me with my old facebook app but not with the new app. Any idea the problem? I changed the app_id and secret for the new app, so that there will not the solution.

My 'users' table:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username',100);
        $table->string('first_name',100)->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name',100)->nullable();
        $table->string('email',100);
        $table->biginteger('uid');
        $table->string('access_token');
        $table->string('access_toker_secret');
        $table->text('remember_token',100);
        $table->string('nickname');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique('username');
        $table->unique('email');

        $table->index('username');
        $table->index('email');
    });
}


public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}

}
```

If I test my old facebook app, my code works normally. Could it be a permissions problem with facebook app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Username in no longer available. For this reason I can't get it. Check this link:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog